# NIntegrate fails to converge near a point that is not inside my definite integral?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to calculate a definite integral.  I write:

```
NIntegrate[expression, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

"expression" is described below.   The WorkingPrecision was added in to help with another error.

I get an error:

> "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed
>   accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {<<156>>}.
>   NIntegrate obtained <<157>> and <<160>> for the integral and error
>   estimates. >>"

Why am I getting this error for `near{x} = {<<156>>}` when I am only looking at `0<x<1`?  And what do the double pointy brackets around the number mean?

The expression is really long, so I think it would be more meaningful to show how I generate it.This is a basic version (some of the exponents I need to be variables, but these are the lowest values, and I still get the error).

```
F[n_] := (1 - (1 - F[n-1])^2)^2;
F[0] = x;
Expr[n_]:= (1/(1-F[n]))Integrate[D[F[n],x]*x,{x,x,1}];
```

I get the error when I integrate Expr[3] or higher.  Oddly, when I use regular Integrate and then //N at the end, I get a complex number for n=2.

Comment: After some experimentation, the error goes away in some cases if I increase working precision, though that's not what the error message help says to do.  When I plot the interval, it comes out very oscillitory in a certain range, though it shouldn't be.  It's a fraction though... perhaps it has to do with the precision being such that the denom. rounds to zero in some points?

Comment: Important general tip in these situations: When you increase WorkingPrecision, note that by default a higher PrecisionGoal is used, which can make the problem a lot harder. If you only require e.g. 6 significant figures, add an explicit setting PrecisionGoal -> 6.

Comment: @Andrew:  Thank you!  I don't require many digits, so that is very helpful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `<<156>>` does not mean that the integral is being evaluated at `x=156`. `<<>>` is called [`Skeleton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Skeleton.html) and is used to indicate that a large output was suppressed. From the documentation:

> `Skeleton[n]`
>   represents a sequence of `n` omitted elements in an expression printed with `Short` or `Shallow`. The standard print form for `Skeleton` is `<<n>>`.

---

Coming to your integral, here's the error that I get:

[image]

So you can see that this long number was suppressed in your case (depending on your preferences). The last `>>` is a link that takes you to the corresponding error message in the documentation.

If you try the advice in the document, which is to increase `MaxRecursion`, you'll eventually get a new error `::slwcon`

[image]

So this now tells you that either your `WorkingPrecision` is too small or that you have a singularity (which is brought on by a small working precision). Increasing `WorkingPrecision` to `200` gives the following output:

[image]

---

You can look a little further into the nature of your expressions.

```
num = Numerator@Expr@3;
den = Denominator@Expr@3;
Plot[{num, den}, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So beyond 0.7ish, your expression has the potential for serious stability issues, resulting in singularities. It is the numerator rather than the denominator, that requires high precision to converge to the right value.

```
num /. x -> 0.99
num /. x -> 0.99`100

Out[1]= -0.015625
Out[2]= 1.2683685178049112809413795626911317545171610885215799438968\
06379991565*10^-14

den /. x -> 0.99
den /. x -> 0.99`100

Out[3]= 1.28786*10^-14
Out[4]= 1.279743968014714505561671861369465844697720803022743298030747945923286\
915425027352809730413954909*10^-14
```

You can see here the difference between the numerator and denominator when you don't have sufficient precision, causing a near singularity.

Comment: Thanks, yoda!  The problem, at that WorkingPrecision, the error comes back for n>3, and when I try to increase it, I get all sorts of other errors.  Do you have any insight as to why this integral is causing these problems?

Comment: I just added a little more detail on where the instability comes in your expression.

Comment: thanks so much!!!  Hopefully just one more question:  why does the numerator round to a negative number when there is not enough precision, as opposed to just zero?  The numerator is never actually negative (you can tell by the logic of the expression), and the greater precision numerator estimate is positive.

Comment: That's just from fluctuation around `0` due to instability. If you keep just the first two terms in the numerator and calculate at `x=0.99`, you get a negative term. What happens at insufficient precision is that the higher order terms are effectively zero. By increasing precision, the tiny contribution from each of those terms compounds and adds up, giving close to the right result.

Comment: Ok, I get it.  Thank you so much for your help!!