# Trying to get Mathematica to approximate an integral

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to get Mathematica to approximate an integral that is a function of various parameters. I don't need it to be extremely precise -- the answer will be a fraction, and 5 digits would be nice, but I'd settle for as few as 2.
The problem is that there is a symbolic integral buried in the main integral, and I can't use NIntegrate on it since its symbolic.

```
    F[x_, c_] := (1 - (1 - x)^c)^c;
    a[n_, c_, x_] := F[a[n - 1, c, x], c];
    a[0, c_, x_] = x;

    MyIntegral[n_,c_] := 
      NIntegrate[Integrate[(D[a[n,c,y],y]*y)/(1-a[n,c,x]),{y,x,1}],{x,0,1}]
```

Mathematica starts hanging when `n`  is greater than 2 and `c` is greater than 3 or so (generally as both `n` and `c` get a little higher).

Are there any tricks for rewriting this expression so that it can be evaluated more easily?  I've played with different `WorkingPrecision` and `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` options on the outer `NIntegrate`, but none of that helps the inner integral, which is where the problem is.  In fact, for the higher values of `n` and `c`, I can't even get Mathematica to expand the inner derivative, i.e.

```
Expand[D[a[4,6,y],y]]
```

hangs.

I am using Mathematica 8 for Students.

If anyone has any tips for how I can get M. to approximate this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: To the individual(s) who voted to close, this is a valid question with regards to the Mathematica programming language and environment. Hence, it is not off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: If you perform the inner integral alone, are there any timing problems? Also, are `n` and `c` supposed to be integers? If so, consider changing the definition of `a` to `a[n_Integer, c_Integer, x_]` as it will prevent infinite recursions.

Comment: @rcollyer: If by timing problem you mean the integral takes a long time or effectively hangs, then yes.  In fact, thinking now, I probably could have just put the inner integral in the question.  Or is there something more specific about timing you are asking?  (I am pretty inexperienced... thank you for your patience.)  I am trying out the Integer thing.. doesn't seem to fix the problem, but still experimenting (and that's a great tip to know about).

Comment: I did not expect the "integer thing" to fix the issue, only make the code a little more reliable. As to `NIntegrate` hanging, I think there are possibly two issues here: 1. the inner integral is taking a long time to evaluate (which you've now said), and 2. `NIntegrate` may be re-evaluating the inner integral for every value of x. Suspecting that it was issue (2), I was wondering if evaluating the inner part symbolically first would help. But, I guess not. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @rcollyer. Oh, now I see what you're getting at.  Although it takes a long time to evaluate the integral on its own, perhaps it will still compute if I wait it out, and then plug it into the NIntegrate which will then run faster.  I hadn't thought about how NIntegrate would compound the problem.  Let me see how this works.  (PS -- the integer tip is very helpful, thanks, as I work with integer based sequences a lot and had no idea I could do that)

Comment: Memoization helps a bit with the timing, but I'm not surprised that it takes a long time for large `n` and `c`. That's a lot of nested `((((()^c)^c)^c...)^c)` in there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you only want a numerical output (or that's what you'll get anyway), you can convert the symbolic integration into a numerical one using just `NIntegrate` as follows:

```
Clear[a,myIntegral]
a[n_Integer?Positive, c_Integer?Positive, x_] := 
  a[n, c, x] = (1 - (1 - a[n - 1, c, x])^c)^c;
a[0, c_Integer, x_] = x;

myIntegral[n_, c_] := 
 NIntegrate[D[a[n, c, y], y]*y/(1 - a[n, c, x]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1},
   WorkingPrecision -> 200, PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

This is much faster than performing the integration symbolically. Here's a comparison:

#### yoda:

```
myIntegral[2,2]//Timing
Out[1]= {0.088441, 0.647376595...}

myIntegral[5,2]//Timing
Out[2]= {1.10486, 0.587502888...}
```

#### rcollyer:

```
MyIntegral[2,2]//Timing
Out[3]= {1.0029, 0.647376}

MyIntegral[5,2]//Timing 
Out[4]= {27.1697, 0.587503006...}
(* Obtained with WorkingPrecision->500, PrecisionGoal->5, MaxRecursion->20 *)
```

Jand's function has timings similar to rcollyer's. Of course, as you increase `n`, you will have to increase your `WorkingPrecision` way higher than this, as [you've experienced in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786906/nintegrate-fails-to-converge-near-a-point-that-is-not-inside-my-definite-integra). Since you said you only need about 5 digits of precision, I've explicitly set `PrecisionGoal` to 5. You can change this as per your needs.

Comment: I have no idea why that didn't occur to me, it should have been the first thing. I'd vote you up, but I'm out of votes and I'd be further contributing to your overwhelming lead.  :P

Comment: @rcollyer:  how can you be out of votes?  Are they limited? (or are you joking?)

Comment: @Jand Yes, votes are limited to a max of 30 per day. Out of those 30, if you vote on more than 10 questions, then you get an additional 10, upto a max of 40 for the day. Depending on how many questions you vote for, you can get capped anywhere between 30 and 40.

Comment: @rcollyer I'll wait for you to catch up _after_ I get the silver :D

Comment: @Jand, not joking. They're limited to 30 votes for both questions and answers, and 10 for just questions.

Comment: Should find where you live and tie you up for a while. Then we'll see who gets the silver first! (Sarcasm is my primary form of humor, please do not interpret the preceding as an actual threat. If it were an actual threat, I doubt I would have posted it on a public forum for all to see.)

Comment: lol @rcollyer I hardly take anything on the internet seriously :P

Comment: actually, that was more for others benefit, I figured you still had your sarcasm detector up and running. That, and I really don't take this whole "rivalry" thing that seriously. We could duel over it, if you feel the need?

Answer (score 2):

To codify the comments, I'd try the following.  First, to eliminate infinite recursion with regards to the variable, `n`, I'd rewrite your functions as

```
F[x_, c_] := (1 - (1-x)^c)^c;
(* see note below *)
a[n_Integer?Positive, c_, x_] := F[a[n - 1, c, x], c];  
a[0, c_, x_] = x;
```

that way `n==0` will actually be a stopping point.  The `?Positive` form is a [PatternTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html), and useful for applying additional conditions to the parameters. I suspect the issue is that `NIntegrate` is re-evaluating the inner `Integrate` for every value of `x`, so I'd pull that evaluation out, like

```
MyIntegral[n_,c_] := 
  With[{ int = Integrate[(D[a[n,c,y],y]*y)/(1-a[n,c,x]),{y,x,1}] },
    NIntegrate[int,{x,0,1}]
  ]
```

where [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) is one of several scoping constructs specifically for creating local constants.

Your comments indicate that the inner integral takes a long time, have you tried simplifying the integrand as it is a derivative of `a` times a function of `a`?  It seems like the result of a chain rule expansion to me.

**Note**: as per Yoda's suggestion in the comments, you can add a cacheing, or memoization, mechanism to `a`.  Change its definition to

```
d:a[n_Integer?Positive, c_, x_] := d = F[a[n - 1, c, x], c];
```

The trick here is that in `d:a[ ... ]`, `d` is a named pattern that is used again in `d = F[...]` cacheing the value of `a` for those particular parameter values.

Comment: Ignore this if I'm not allowed to ask, but why doesn't the formatting in my comment work?  I copied the syntax from comments left on the question...  I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: @Jand, sorry. I was trying a change of variables on my system and it crept into my answer. Fixed now. Incidentally, to mark something as inline code wrap it in grave marks, `.

Comment: Ah, I see it was fixed before I even posted the first comment. So I deleted it. Thanks for the formatting tip, I will test it out now ```Does this look like code?```

Comment: @Jand, there's also a Help link below the "Add Comment" button which details more of the mark up.

Comment: Though I accepted yoda's answer, I still learned a lot of generally useful information from your answer.  So, thank you very much for taking the time to type it up.

Comment: @Jand, you're welcome. He did have the better answer, though, so there's no jealousy on my part.

Comment: I didn't write my previous comment because I thought you felt bad -- just wanted to let on my appreciation for now knowing how to limit variables to positive integers and use the With construct and memoization.  Your explanations made the concepts easy to grasp as well as providing syntax.